# React Native: Chrome Debuger with Android and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, debugging, react-native

I am trying to debug my application with Chrome debuger. Everything works fine on iOS (with and without the debuger) and on Android without but when i use the debuger with Android, I can't manage to do Firebase requests and I have this error :

> "YellowBox.js:67 Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
>   (Saw setTimeout with duration 556163ms)".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This error is not important. you can fix it like this.

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
}
```

And for display log in google chrome debuger just open this link in your browser

#### http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is, I can't access to firebase on my Android emulator, I thought it was related to the YellowBox problem, apparently not. On my iOS device (while using google chrome debugger), it displays : "SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert" before accessing to firebase, with the Android (and the debugger) it doesn't tell me that and it isn't able to connect to firebase.